# updating values in JSON using PUT method

Tags: json, powershell, nested, put

I have a nested JSON file. I want to update some values with PUT method. I can change some values, but the problem is in the nested values.

```bsh
$Authorization = "Bearer API-KEY"

$update = [ordered]@{
    name       = 'ppp'
    asset_tag  = 'BBB'
    custom_fields = @(
        [ordered] @{
            Mediensatz = @(
                [ordered] @{
                    value = "B2T-XXX"
                }
            )
        } 
    )
}
$json = $update | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

#Write-Host $json
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'URL' -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{'Authorization' = $Authorization}
```

My JSON file look like this:

```json
{
    "total": 888,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "AAA",
            "asset_tag": "CCC",
            "model": {
                "id": 34,
                "name": "TTT"
            },
            "user_can_checkout": true,
            "custom_fields": {
                "Mediensatz": {
                    "field": "lll",
                    "value": "B2T-YYY",
                    "field_format": "ANY"
                },
                "Ueberschreibschutz": {
                    "field": "lll",
                    "value": "2019-07-10",
                    "field_format": "DATE"
                }
            }
        }
```

I can change the "name" and "asset_tag", but the problem is "value" in *custom_fields → Mediensatz → value*.

When I try to run my code with `Write-Host $json` it's look like this:

```json
{
    "name": "PPP",
    "asset_tag": "BBB",
    "custom_fields": [
        {
            "Mediensatz": [
                 {
                     "value":  "B2T-XXX"
                 }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Remove the `@()` after `custom_fields` and `Mediensatz`

Comment: same result @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: same result what? The JSON looks the same? You can't set new value of `$update.custom_fields.Mediensatz.value`? Or the web server is throwing an error?

Comment: the web server is throwing an error @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Please post the (full) error message in the question then

Comment: can you write an example for $update.custom_fields.Mediensatz.value @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: `$update.custom_fields.Mediensatz.value = "New-Value"`